# How to get first item from product collection

Tags: category, products, product-collection

On the category view.phtml if I get the category and then get a product collection, how can I get the first product form the collection assigned to $_product for use in the code? Here is what I have:

```
$_category   = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
$_product    = 
$_resource   = $_product->getResource();
```

I tried using foreach but kept getting errors.

Comment: `$_product = $_collection->getFirstItem()`

Comment: @pzirkind put this answer.please don't put it comment

Comment: I tried this but getting error - Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View::canEmailToFriend(Array))

Comment: @heisenberg that meand you are trying to call a function that doesn't exixt, either way, its a different error (not connected with your original question), either update your question with the new code or start a new one

Comment: @danny if you found an answer here, please accept to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 29):

To get the first item in a collection simply use the `getFirstItem()` function on the collection.

Example:

```
// this gets all the products
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/products_collection');
// this line gets just the first product
$firstItem = $productCollection->getFirstItem();
```

Example 2 (for this particular question):

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$_collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
$_product =  $_collection->getFirstItem(); // this will get first item in collection
```

Some other areas this can be used:

**Customers**

```
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
$firstCustomer = $customerCollection->getFirstItem();
```

**Orders**

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
$firstOrder = $orderCollection->getFirstItem();
```

Please Note:

Its not a good idea to load ALL the products/customers/orders for this takes a lot of resources. The preferred way is to limit what you want to load by using the `addAttributeToFilter()` or `addFieldToFilter()` functions, see example below:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                           ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'book123`);
```

Answer (score 5):

[pzirkind](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/24164/46249) is totally correct, just wondering that nobody takes care about performance. If you **ONLY** want the first/last item of a collection, you should **always** limit your query to `1`:

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

Just using `getFirstItem()` will still **loads the whole collection** and after that it grags the first item.

---

***Example***: category with 750 products

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(41);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
# $collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
var_dump($collection->getSelect()->__toString());
var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```

Just `getFirstItem()`:

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    2,318,497 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 2,000,604 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  7,729,776 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  7,977,672 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    96,957

Adding `getSelect()->limit(1)`:

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 424,955 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  380,326 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   4,043,728 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   3,976,000 bytes
- Number of Function Calls: 15,249

Comment: This is ideal as it covers two solutions, and supplies execution times, and explains performance benefits  +1

Answer (score 4):

```
var_dump($_collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
echo $_collection->getFirstItem()->getName();
```

Also how to get Last Item:

```
echo $_collection->getLastItem()->getName();
var_dump($_collection->getLastItem()->getData());
```

Answer (score 2):

@pZirKind is right you can get the first item from the products collection using the native methods of Varien Collection class like:

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();

$_collection = $_category->getProductCollection();

$_product = $_collection->getFirstItem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();        
    $_collection = $_category->getProductCollection();        
    $_items = $_productCollection->getItems(); 
   if($_items){  
    $_items[0]->getShortName();
    $_items[0]->getProductUrl();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/products_collection');
$firstItem = $Collection->getFirstItem();
```