# How to get first product from category in 1column.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, category-attribute

I'm searching for a way to get the main image from the first (or random) product from the **current category** and use it as a background for the category title.

As the title is created in `1column.phtml` (or `2columns-left.phtml`, `2columns-right.phtml`, `3columns.phtml`), the code should work there. I've tried all different solutions from [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24076/how-to-get-first-item-from-product-collection) post, but it just gives me errors.

According to the code in 1column.phtml I've tried to get something like this as a first step inside :

```
<header class="page-header">
    <div class="container">...</div>
</header>
```

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category') : ?>
<h1 class="title"><?php echo $_category->name ?></h1>
<?php echo $_category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem()->getName(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This was an attempt that doesn't give back errors, but has no output at all. I'm pretty sure there is a was, but I'm clueless how to call anything useful within `1column.phtml`.

Comment: Are you sure there is at least one product in the category that you have tested? And try to print $_category->getProductCollection()->getSelect() and paste the output query here

Answer (score 2):

Please use registry variable for this case.

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category') : 
    if ($_category = Mage::registry('current_category')) :
        $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
?>
        <h1 class="title"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        <?php echo $_category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem()->getName(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif ;?>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. However this gives me an error: 
**Fatal error: Call to a member function categoryAttribute() on a non-object in /.../app/design/frontend/progressive/default/template/page/1column.phtml on line 172**
If I add '<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>' on top of 1column.phtml, the client side looks normal, but there is no output from 'echo $_category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem()->getName();'

Comment: answer update ...

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't give any output of 'echo $_category->getProductCollection()->getFirstItem()->getName();' aswell. 
Output is just: 
<header class="page-header">
<div class="container">
<h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
</header>